# SED command to get nth tab separated value between lines x and y

Tags: linux, sed, pattern-matching

I have been able to extract certain lines from a large tab-separated text file and write them to another file:

```
sed -n 100,200p file.tsv >> output.txt
```

However, I am actually trying to grab the **8th tab-separated value** from each line and write them to a file comma separated, but I cannot find the right syntax to use for the pattern matching, despite reading dozens of online articles.

For each time I have basically been trying to match

`$2` in `/([^\t]*\t){7}([0-9]*).*/`

with no luck.

The lines within the text file file.tsv resemble:

```
01  name1   title1  summary1    desc1   image1  url1    120019  time1
02  name2   title2  summary2    desc2   image2  url2    576689  time2
```

Please can anyone help me with this query?

Comment: could you provide a sample line?

Comment: I've added the format above, and have tried rather poorly with commands such as:   
  
 
`sed -e '100,/start/ s/[^\t]\t[^\t]\t[^\t]\t[^\t]\t[\t^]\t[^\t]\t[^\t]\t//' -e '/stop/,200 s/\t.*//' file.tsv`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is using GNU sed and extended expressions:

```
sed -nre '100,200{s/^(\S+\s+){7}(\S+).*$/\2/;p}' file.tsv
```

Here it is using POSIX only:

```
sed -n '100,200{s/^\([^[:space:]]\+[[:space:]]\+\)\{7\}\([^[:space:]]\+\).*$/\2/;p}' file.tsv
```

I do agree with Alf that `awk` would be a better fit for this.

Here is the `awk` solution with line limits:

```
awk 'NR==100,NR==200{print $8}' file.tsv
```

Comment: If you need to keep white space other than tabs, replace all `[:space:]` with `\t` in the POSIX version.

Comment: That is ideal. Thank you for that solution. You have solved my problem perfectly, and I can see form that how I might modify it as well. Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I think I would rather use awk that way:

```
$ awk '{ print col 8 : $8 }' file
```

The forward work will be easier I guess.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, unfortunately I am not familiar with how to use that syntax with tabbed files.

Answer (score 2):

A Perl one-liner:

```
perl -F'\t' -ane 'push @csv, $F[7] if $. > 100 && $. < 200; END { print join ",", @csv if @csv }' /path/to/input/file > /path/to/output/file
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your quick reply! That looks ideal. The only problem us the data is tab separated instead of comma separated so it didn't match the right columns. How might I make that change please?

Comment: Don: Hi. You are welcome. I have edited my answer to add an explicit `\t` as the field separator. It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

This will work if there are empty fields.

```
sed -nre '100,200{s/^(([^\t]*)\t){7}([^\t]*)(\t.*|$)/\3/;p}' file.tsv
```